# SQL grouping of get not associated to any post

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
Hour    Operation   IP
10  GET     192.168.1.3
10  POST    192.168.1.3
10  GET     192.168.1.4
10  GET     192.168.1.8
12  POST    192.168.1.7
12  GET     192.168.1.7
12  GET     192.168.1.9
```

And I need to know for each hour how many different GET operations without a POST operation associated (visits with no purchases)

The answer would be:

```
Hour GETs
10 2
12 1
```

But I have no clue about how to do this.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: What have you tried so far????  SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: Visits with no purchases? Surely the web app itself should be tracking that? You can't rely on GET/POST to give you that info - the POST could be any number of things!

Comment: It's part of a Hadoop exercise with hive, so, more of less standard SQL. I'm triying to solve it with a collect function but I'd like to know if it can be done with standard SQL

Comment: Isaace, it doesn't work because you are checking that an IP associated to a GET is not in a POST within all the table and that comparison should be done within the grouping hour, that's what I can not solve.

Comment: I fixed it to take that into account. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: It works like a charm!!!

Comment: I didn't know you can use an alias of a table to filter the same table within a group by!!

Comment: AND NOT EXISTS is just a filter that narrows down the results to those that don't have posts for that ID in that hour and the GROUP BY is a regular GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
 SELECT HOUR, COUNT(IP) FROM 
 (
   SELECT HOUR, IP FROM mytable a WHERE Operation = 'GET' and NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT 1 FROM mytable b WHERE Operation = 'POST' AND a.IP = b.IP AND 
      a.HOUR = b.HOUR
    )
) as a
GROUP BY HOUR
```

Or even shorter:

```
SELECT HOUR, COUNT(IP) 
FROM mytable a 
WHERE Operation = 'GET' 
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM mytable b 
  WHERE Operation = 'POST' 
  AND a.IP = b.IP 
  AND a.HOUR = b.HOUR
)
GROUP BY HOUR
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think you want:

```
select hour, sum(case when posts > gets then gets - posts else 0 end)
from (select ip, hour,
             sum(case when operation = 'GET' then 1 else 0 end) as gets,
             sum(case when operation = 'POST' then 1 else 0 end) as posts
      from t
      group by ip, hour
     ) ih
group by hour;
```

This is rather tricky, because presumably a given IP could have multiple gets and puts in the same hour.